# Installing programs using .msi files get stuck in the progress bar screen in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-installer

I am having trouble installing some programs using .msi installers, and the problem seems to be same in all the cases

After pressing next on all screens, when it reaches the point where there is a progress bar and it is supposed to be copying files to the required folders, the program seems to get stuck and the progress bar doesn't progress at all (the green line doesn't even start). The window is still responsive and I can click the cancel button, X and minimize buttons and drag the window around, but the installation does not seem to move forward. Some msi files close cleanly when just pressing cancel, while others don't close so easily, and hang around in memory if the window is gone, and I have to forcefully close all instances of them from task manager. As an example, I am trying to install [keyman developer 13.0 for windows](https://keyman.com/developer/download). The setup file I am using is `keymandeveloper-13.0.111.0.exe` (size 97,907,344 bytes). If I open the exe file using 7zip I can see there is an msi file and an inf file inside.

What is happening here and how do I fix it? Does the Windows msi installer keep a log of what is going on?

Windows version: Windows 10 Pro 1909 build 18363.1016
Computer : HP laptop with AMD Ryzen 3 3200U with Radeon Vega Mobile gfx 2.60 GHz

Comment: Did you run the installation as administrator?

Comment: @Binarus yes...